# Converting tensorflow keras model to coreml model

Tags: keras, tf.keras, coreml, coremltools

I am currently working on a personal project and having some trouble trying to convert a trained RNN model to coreml to import into xcode. I have the model saved and successfully loaded to be able to make predictions but when I run this line of code
`model1 = ct.convert(model) model1.save('stockmodel.mlmodel') print('model converted')` I get this in the terminal from pycharm.
[image: Pycharm Terminal Screenshot]

I am new to this and not sure what exactly is going on. My model takes in a collection of data in the form of a .csv file as well as an int to define the time in the future to predict to. Anyone guidance and help would be very appreciated as I have looked over many article and can't seem to understand how to convert it properly.

Also the `ct` come from this `import coremltools as ct`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that before `coremltools` 5 was released, Python 3.9 was not supported.

Please see:

https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/1214